# My post falls between two If statements, what can I do?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I'm trying to filter out various things for the meta portion of my **WordPress** website, and I've found an issue, using the following code was working perfectly until I needed to get a bit more specific.

```
if (is_singular('post')) {
        $title = get_the_title ();
        print '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
        $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        print '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$feat_image.'"/>';
        print '<meta name="description" content="" />';
    } else {
        print '<title></title>';
        print '<meta name="description" content="" />';         
}
```

Note that I edited the *meta descriptions* above so that they're empty, just for the sake of posting on stack.

Then I wanted to start filtering based on the tags a post has, and obviously this is going to conflict with the already declared `(is_singular('post'))` function above.

However, I used the code below.

```
if ( has_tag( 'spanish' )) {
        print '<title>'.$title.'</title>';
        $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        print '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$feat_image.'"/>';
        print '<meta name="description" content="" />';
}
```

And it is displaying the meta for this portion also in the category we wish for it too, how ever it's also displaying the **meta description** for the other function as well, what can I do stack?

Answer (score -1):

This might sound simplistic, but firstly you want to document exactly what you want to happen. Maybe make yourself a flow chart or write a couple of paragraphs. Either way, you need to know from a non-code point of view first. This will enable you to answer questions like "Does a tag take precedence over a single post?" Once you know this process, move your conditions away from output to simplify the process. Something like this:

```
// defaults
$title = '...';
$metaDescription = '...';
$featuredImage = '...';

// overrides for difference scenarios
if (is_singular('post')) {
  // set title, etc here
}
if (has_tag('spanish')) {
  // override or concatenate title, etc here
}

// output
print "<title>$title</title>";
<!-- etc etc -->
```

Comment: Sure would be helpful if the downvoter explained what's wrong with my answer?